# in drupal how to display 2 views with filter exposed in same page/path?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

in drupal how to display 2 views with filter exposed in same page/path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried having each view as a block?  That way it is simple to have two different views on the same page - for example add the blocks to the body and limit them to the specific page.   caveat - I don't know if exposing the filter makes using the block view problematic, but it is certainly worth a try.

Comment: steps: 1. create view  2. set filters exposed (i used these two views as searching purpose) 3.Exposed form (Exposed form in block: Yes) 4. set this two views block in a region. it shows two form but when search no content shows (it goes to home page)

Comment: for that i remove block and in views add display as a page for two different view  and set the page path in same link/page then one views shows and works but i need to show both the views in same page.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is described here:

1. Create a view with two "page" displays
2. Make sure the filters are identical in both
3. Under exposed form set "Exposed form in block" to "Yes" in both
   displays
4. Make the second display appear in the footer of the first
5. Set the exposed block to appear only in the path of the first
   display

Now setting filters affects both displays.